# Show Hide Error Message After 5ms in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to show an error message inside a div and I want it to stay 5ms alive after that it will disappear and when the next message will come it will be live again. 
I am trying like this:

```
<div id="error"> <UserSignupMessagesView /> </div> 

 $(".error").slideDown();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".error").slideUp();
        }, 5000);
```

But it is not helping at all. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserSignupMessagesView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{
      display: 0,
      message: ""
    }
  },
  changeDisplay: function(count){
    this.setState({display: this.state.display + count})
  },
  setErrorMsg: function(message){
    this.setState({message: message})
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
      <ErrorGenerator newMessage={this.setErrorMsg}
                      displayOrNot={this.changeDisplay}/>
      {(this.state.display!=0) ?
      <DisplayIt message = {this.state.message} />
      : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

  var ErrorGenerator = React.createClass({
    handleUserInput: function(){
      this.props.newMessage($("#input").val());
      //**handle displaying and hiding of the message state
      this.props.displayOrNot(1);
      setTimeout(function(self) {
           self.props.displayOrNot(-1);
       }, 5000, this);
      //**
    },
    render: function(){
      return(
      <div>
      demo: input an error: <input id = "input" type= "text" /><br />
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleUserInput}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  var DisplayIt = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return   <div id = "error"> {this.props.message} </div>
    }
  });

  React.render(
    <UserSignupMessagesView />,
    document.getElementById('myDiv')
  )
```

Im not sure how your error is generated, so I made a input textbox to simulate that (the ErrorGenerator component). Everytime you hit 'click me' it will display the newly typed Msg, then after 5 second it will disappear. If you enter a new msg and hit 'click me' before the 5 second ends, it will count the 5 second for you again.